# CSS3 FlexBox layout and Android scrollbar issue

Tags: android, css, mobile, flexbox

I'm trying to define a basic CSS mobile layout using flexbox only, and that supports both iOS and Android with the various syntaxes. Its working nicely for the sizing, except the Android scrollbar on Chrome looks to have an initial offset.

live demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/11MJsXIAFKcYGna4Eytm?p=preview

sample CSS:

```
/* flexbox layout
    - applied to body but can be any container
    - combine all webkit syntaxes
*/
html, body {
    height:100%;  
}
body {
  position:relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow:column;
  flex-flow:column;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.header {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  height:40px;
  min-height:40px;
  -webkit-box-flex:0;
  -webkit-flex:0 1 auto;
  flex:0 1 auto;
  // inner shadow
  z-index:10000;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px -5px #333;
}
.content {
  position:relative;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  min-height: 0px;
}
.footer {
  height:64px;
  min-height:64px;
  -webkit-box-flex:0;
  -webkit-flex:0 1 auto;
  flex:0 1 auto;
  // inner shadow
  z-index:10000;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #333;
}
```

sample HTML :

```
<body>
    <div class="header">FlexBox layout demo</div>
    <div class="content">long blbalbalaba</div>
    <div class="footer">bottom toolbar</div>
</body>
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong ?

Thank you :)

Env: Chrome 29 on Android nexus 4 4.3

Comment: I've had alot of trouble earlier getting overflow to work on all mobile browsers with only css. I ended up using a jQuery plugin: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/, might be something to consider.

Comment: You *must* provide enough code in the question to reproduce the problem (see:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/x77uhkro).

Comment: sorry i missed to specify the 100% height on html/body. fixed.